# Guess the formula for $\sum\frac 1{(4n-3)(4n+1)}$ and prove by induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

> For $n \ge 1$, let
>   $$a_n = \dfrac1{1 \cdot 5} + \dfrac1{5 \cdot 9} + \cdots + \dfrac1{(4n-3)(4n+1)}.$$
>   Guess a simple explicit formula for $a_n$ and prove it by induction.

So I have guessed the formula as : $$\frac{n}{4n+1}$$

But wasn't sure how to prove it by induction

Comment: hint: $\frac4{(4x-3)(4x+1)}=\frac1{4x-3}-\frac1{4x+1}$

Comment: Just need to show $a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac {1}{(4(n+1)-3)(4(n+1) + 1}= \frac {n}{4n+1}+ \frac {1}{(4n+1)(4n + 5)}= \frac {n+1}{4(n+1)+1} = \frac {n+1}{4n + 5}$.  That should be very straightforward.

Comment: ... because $\frac {n}{4n+1}+ \frac {1}{(4n+1)(4n + 5)} = \frac {n(4n+5) + 1}{(4n+1)(4n+5)} = \frac {4n^2 + 5n+ 1}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}=\frac {(4n+1)(n+1)}{(4n+1)(4n+5)} = \frac {n+1}{4n+5}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base case:

$$a_1=\frac1{4(1)+1}\color{green}\checkmark$$

Now the inductive step:

$$\begin{align}a_{n+1}&=a_n+\frac1{(4n+1)(4n+5)}\\&=\frac n{4n+1}+\frac1{(4n+1)(4n+5)}\\&=\frac{n(4n+5)}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}+\frac1{(4n+1)(4n+5)}\\&=\frac{4n^2+5n+1}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}\\&=\frac{(4n+1)(n+1)}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}\\&=\frac{n+1}{4(n+1)+1}\color{green}\checkmark\end{align}$$

and we are done.

Comment: sorry may I ask why its (4n + 5) ?

Comment: @M.Jones Where do you mean?

Comment: @M.Jones: it is from plugging $n+1$ in for $n$ in the given sum. $4n+1 \implies 4(n+1)+1 = 4n + 5$

Comment: ahh okay I see !

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
a_{n} & \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{4k - 3}\pars{4k + 1}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{4k - 4}\,\dd x\int_{0}^{1}y^{4k}\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\bracks{\pars{xy}^{4}}^{k}
\,{\dd x \over x^{4}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}y^{3}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{xy}^{4}\,{\pars{xy}^{4n} - 1 \over \pars{xy}^{4} - 1}\,{y\,\dd x \over \pars{xy}^{4}}\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}y^{3}\int_{0}^{y}{x^{4n} - 1 \over x^{4} - 1}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4n} - 1 \over x^{4} - 1}\int_{x}^{1}y^{3}\,\dd y\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4n} - 1 \over x^{4} - 1}{1 - x^{4} \over 4}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x^{4n}}\,\dd x = {1 \over 4}\pars{1 - {1 \over 4n + 1}} =
\bbx{n \over 4n + 1}
\end{align}

> 'Induction' was
>   [already shown by $\texttt{@Simply Beautiful Art}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2284358/85343).

Comment: This is not what was asked for. It would be OK if you preface it by saying this is an alternative method, just for interest, or something to that effect.

Comment: @Deepak The OP ask for an explicit formula. I found an explicit one.

Comment: The question was to *guess* at an explicit formula (which generally involves only elementary pattern recognition), then *prove* it by induction (which your answer does not). While your solution certainly does find the explicit formula (without guesswork or induction), it does not answer the question. As I said, that would be fine as long as you preface it accordingly.

Comment: @Deepak I didn't include 'induction' because $\texttt{@Simply Beautiful Art}$ already did it.

Comment: In which case your answer would be redundant unless you stated that it was an alternative method, purely for interest.

Comment: Edited noted, downvote removed.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks. Don't worry. Those are the MSE-rules. I'm not very good at 'guessing'.

Comment: It actually is a beautiful solution. It's good that you added it, and clarified that it's an alternative solution to what was asked for.